# Extracting values from JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json, discogs-api

I am currently experimenting with the Discogs API, using PHP. My query against their API is returned as JSON, which I can decoding using:

```
$trackMeta = json_decode($trackMeta, true);
```

I'd then like to be able to access certain elements within the data that is returned. Using `print_r($trackMeta);`outputs the below data:

```
Array ( [pagination] => Array ( [per_page] => 1 [pages] => 7 [page] => 1 [urls] => Array ( [last] => http://api.discogs.com/database/search?artist=siren&q=snorkel&per_page=1&page=7 [next] => http://api.discogs.com/database/search?artist=siren&q=snorkel&per_page=1&page=2 ) [items] => 7 ) [results] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [style] => Array ( [0] => Drum n Bass ) [thumb] => http://api-img.discogs.com/cf1HxM29IXQKNsSdrwYioa0uEeI=/fit-in/150x150/filters:strip_icc():format(jpeg):mode_rgb()/discogs-images/R-3581480-1336678182-5777.jpeg.jpg [format] => Array ( [0] => Vinyl [1] => 12" [2] => 45 RPM ) [country] => UK [barcode] => Array ( ) [uri] => /Siren-21-Vicious-Circle-Snorkel-SPY-Remix-Solitude/master/433189 [community] => Array ( [want] => 66 [have] => 81 ) [label] => Array ( [0] => Siren Records ) [catno] => SIREN001 [year] => 2012 [genre] => Array ( [0] => Electronic ) [title] => Siren (21) / Vicious Circle (3) - Snorkel (S.P.Y. Remix) / Solitude [resource_url] => http://api.discogs.com/masters/433189 [type] => master [id] => 433189 ) ) )
```

When trying to use a foreach loop on `$trackMeta`, I can only return 171 which I believe relates to `per_page` pages and `page`.

How can I access data deeper in this array? For example values such as thumb or year or genre?

Comment: try like `$trackMeta[urls]` to access a specific subarray

Comment: Clean up your post.  How is anyone supposed to read that array, including yourself.  Don't look at the HTML rendered print out, look at the source or command line output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$trackMeta` is an associative array:

```
$trackMeta = array (
    'pagination' => array (
        'per_page' => 1,
        'pages' => 7,
        'page' => 1,
        'urls' => array (
            'last' => 'http://api.discogs.com/database/search?artist=siren&q=snorkel&per_page=1&page=7',
            'next' => 'http://api.discogs.com/database/search?artist=siren&q=snorkel&per_page=1&page=2'
        ),
        'items' => 7
    ),
    'results' => array (
        0 => array (
            'style' => array (
                0 => 'Drum n Bass'
            ),
            'thumb' => 'http://api-img.discogs.com/cf1HxM29IXQKNsSdrwYioa0uEeI=/fit-in/150x150/filters:strip_icc():format(jpeg):mode_rgb()/discogs-images/R-3581480-1336678182-5777.jpeg.jpg',
            'format' => array (
                0 => 'Vinyl',
                1 => '12"',
                2 => '45 RPM'
            ),
            'country' => 'UK',
            'barcode' => array ( ),
            'uri' => '/Siren-21-Vicious-Circle-Snorkel-SPY-Remix-Solitude/master/433189',
            'community' => array (
                'want' => 66,
                'have' => 81
            ),
            'label' => array (
                0 => 'Siren Records'
            ),
            'catno' => 'SIREN001',
            'year' => 2012,
            'genre' => array (
                0 => 'Electronic'
            ),
            'title' => 'Siren (21) / Vicious Circle (3) - Snorkel (S.P.Y. Remix) / Solitude',
            'resource_url' => 'http://api.discogs.com/masters/433189',
            'type' => 'master',
            'id' => 433189
        )
    )
);
```

For example, you can access `thumb` with the following code:

`print_r($trackMeta['results'][0]['thumb']);`